# Explicit expression for coefficients of arbitrary integer powers of power series?

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

For $n=2,4,6,\dots$, define
$$
f_n(x)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k.
$$
Certainly, for $n=2$ we have the Cauchy product
$$
f_2(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{\ell=0}^ka_{k-\ell}a_\ell x^k.
$$
For higher orders of $n$ I am aware that we also have the Faà di Bruno's formula. My main interest is in an explicit expression for the coefficients $c_k$ for arbitrary $n$. A recurrence relation would be fine as well. My hope is that this has already been worked out and I will not have to drudge through Faà di Bruno to work it out from scratch.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Power_series_raised_to_powers

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thank you! Was looking in the wrong place.